# Unable to register snapshot repository for AWS elasticsearch in fs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-snapshot

I am trying to register a snapshot repository on AWS Elasticsearch/OpenSearch. I am getting the following error: `"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::$$$$$:user/Elasticsearch"}`

Below is my curl command:

```
curl -XPUT http://search-ecs-alblogs-@@@@@.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_snapshot/es_snap -d \
'{
    "type":"fs",
    "settings":{
        "location":"home/user/backup",
        "compress":true,
        "access_key":"@@@@@@",
        "secret_key":"@@@@",
        "region":"us-west-2",
        "role_arn":"arn:aws:iam::@@@@@:user/Elasticsearch"
    }
}'
```

Comment: I would say your user doensn’t have needed permission, so you need to add them appropriately

Comment: That's why I am passing access_key and secret_key of the user having permission. the user is an AWS IAM user .

Answer (score 1):

AWS Elasticsearch doesn't allow you to store snapshots on type 'fs". All snapshots must be stored in S3.

For more detail, you can read through documentation: [Creating index snapshots in Amazon OpenSearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html)